# Problems with deserializing xml to object structure c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have the following xml:

```
<Root>
<ProcessingUnit>Lifestyle</ProcessingUnit>
<ProcessingData>
    <ProcessType>Product</ProcessType>
    <ProcessAction>Create</ProcessAction>
    <Id>7</Id>
</ProcessingData>
</Root>
```

And i have the following object structure

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class XmlRoot
{
    ProcessingUnit ProcessingUnit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ProcessingData")]
    ProcessingData ProcessingData { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessingData
{
    public ProcessType ProcessType { get; set; }
    public ProcessAction ProcessAction { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When i deserialize i do the following:

```
XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRoot));
using (var reader = new StringReader(stringtest))
{
     var tradeData = (XmlRoot)_serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Deserializing to enums works fine, the processingUnit is deserialized correctly but the property `ProcessingData` is `null`.

I have tried decorating with a lot of different xml attributes but i cant see why i get the null value.

**EDIT:**
The stringtest variable has the value:

```
var stringtest =
            "<Root><ProcessingUnit>Lifestyle</ProcessingUnit><ProcessingData><ProcessType>Product</ProcessType><ProcessAction>Create</ProcessAction><Id>7</Id></ProcessingData></Root>";
```

The enums looks like this:

```
public enum ProcessType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Product")]
    Product,

    [XmlEnum(Name = "Category")]
    Category,
}

public enum ProcessAction
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Create")]
    Create,

    [XmlEnum(Name = "Delete")]
    Delete,

    [XmlEnum(Name = "Update")]
    Update,
}

public enum ProcessingUnit
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "LifeStyle")]
    LifeStyle
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `stringtest` contains the actual xml? I can´t see any errors on the code you´ve provided.

Comment: The serialized needs parametetless constructors for the objects being serialized/deserialized. Are you sure, that ProcessingAction and ProcessingType do provide these?

Comment: Thansk for the reply, See edit :)

Comment: Try making the properties of the `XmlRoot` class public.

Comment: Making them public i now get the error "There is an error in XML document (1, 50)". This is the point where the ProcessingData element starts. Strange but now i guess i am closer to the problem, thanks :)

Comment: Now try removing that `XmlElement` attribute from the `ProcessingData` property.

Answer (score 1):

Properties have to be public

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stringtest = "<Root>" +
                "<ProcessingUnit>Lifestyle</ProcessingUnit>" +
                "<ProcessingData>" +
                    "<ProcessType>Product</ProcessType>" +
                    "<ProcessAction>Create</ProcessAction>" +
                    "<Id>7</Id>" +
                "</ProcessingData>" +
                "</Root>";

            XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRoot));
            using (var reader = new StringReader(stringtest))
            {
                XmlRoot tradeData = (XmlRoot)_serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }


        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class XmlRoot
    {
        [XmlElement("ProcessingUnit")]
        public ProcessingUnit ProcessingUnit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ProcessingData")]
        public ProcessingData ProcessingData { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ProcessingData")]
    public class ProcessingData
    {
        [XmlElement("ProcessType")]
        public ProcessType ProcessType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ProcessAction")]
        public ProcessAction ProcessAction { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ProcessingUnit")]
    public class ProcessingUnit
    {
        [XmlText] 
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ProcessType")]
    public class ProcessType
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ProcessAction")]
    public class ProcessAction
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your example and it works - but it does not work when i use the enums instead of strings, then i get the error "There is an error in XML document (1, 50)"

Comment: enums are integers, not strings.

Comment: @jdweng That's true in memory, but not with the XML serializer.  By default, the `XmlSerializer` does indeed use the string names for enums rather than the integer values.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, yes that is also what i see from examples.